# Vagrant - Ansible error installing Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vagrant, ansible

I'm working on a project with Vagrant and Ansible and Virtualbox.
When I try to install Apache on an ubuntu precise (14.04) box, Vagrant fails. I improved the answer after.

It seems a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1312533), but even if I'm installing a newer version, the error shows up.
I tried also as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530872/problem-when-reinstall-apache2-ubuntu-14-04), but with no luck.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**

This is the Ansible task.
Version 1:

```
- name: Install Apache
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg=apache2 state=latest
  register: apache2_apt
```

Output:

```
failed: [default] => {"failed": true}
stderr: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

stdout: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 183 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/146 kB of archives.
After this operation, 460 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 52932 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2 (from .../apache2_2.4.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+5_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 error setting ownership of `/var/www/html.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+5_amd64.deb

msg: '/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"   install 'apache2'' failed: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Version 2:

```
- name: Install Apache
  command: "sudo apt-get install apache2"
  register: apache2_apt
```

Output:

```
failed: [default] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sudo", "apt-get", "install", "apache2"], "delta": "0:00:07.745095", "end": "2015-06-09 11:08:53.726031", "rc": 100, "start": "2015-06-09 11:08:45.980936", "warnings": []}
stderr: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
stdout: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 183 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/146 kB of archives.
After this operation, 460 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 52932 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2 (from .../apache2_2.4.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+5_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 error setting ownership of `/var/www/html.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+5_amd64.deb

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: Could you show the ansible task?

Comment: Is it version 1 or version 2 that gives you the message you have quoted?

Comment: Unfortunately, both of them.

Comment: Are you certain it is _exactly_ the same message in both cases? Have you compared them byte by byte?

Comment: Non exactly the same, above you can view the outputs.

Comment: Do you have `sudo_user` specified in `ansible.cfg`? Could you verify these tasks are being executed as root?

Comment: I checked and in `ansible.cfg`, `sudo_user` is set to root. I also set `sudo: true` in my playbook.yml. The strange thing is that if I log in with vagrant ssh and I try to setup apache manually (with `sudo apt-get install apache2`), I receive the same error stated above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80051/discussion-between-antonis-christofides-and-stuzzo).

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible issues for this

- You need to disable apparmor or better add a rule to apparmor service for ability to have access by the script to /var/www within guest machine
- There is a trouble with host machine permissions for /var/www folder. Try to check if the user has access to local folder, mapped as shared folder from host to guest - possibly you need to add permissions for local user at host machine.
- try to use ansible-galaxy and search for already created role with fixes for both previous issues

Comment: Check my last comment in my original question. I think that isn't an Ansible problem, however I'll try to download another role from ansible-galaxy.